# Public and internal interfaces for a single class

Tags: c#, interface

I have several business objects in my solution. All of them are internal classes which implement an internal interface for unit testing benefits and general exchangeability reasons (IoC). Some of those objects have additionally public interfaces to make them accessible from other assemblies. In those cases the internal interface would inherit the public one. The public interfaces afford limited access to the object. For example:

```
public interface IMyObject
{
    String Color { get; }
}

internal interface IMyObjectInternal : IMyObject
{
    new String Color { get; set; }

    void InternalMagic();
}

internal class MyObject : IMyObjectInternal
{
    String Color = "Red";

    String IMyObject.Color
    {
        get { return this.Color; }
    }

    String IMyObjectInternal.Color
    {
        get { return this.Color; }
        set { this.Color = value; }
    }

    void IMyObjectInternal.InternalMagic() { }
}
```

Is this a practicable approach or should I use internal abstract classes instead of internal interfaces? Please consider that I use an IoC container to create the object instances anonymously.

Comment: 127 views and not a single suggestion :-(